# Function in R to get difference between two sets of polygons comparable in speed to QGIS

Tags: qgis, r, differences, erase, st-difference

I have two very large polygon shapefiles for which I need to calculate the difference between the two shapefiles. One is a shapefile of forest polygons, the other is a shapefile of road polygons. I want to remove the area of the forest polygons that intersects with road polygons, while maintaining each polygon as a separate feature and its data.

After much trial and error, I found that `erase` using the `sp` format or using `st_erase` using the `sf` format performs the operation that I need.

```
st_erase = function(x, y) st_difference(x, st_union(st_combine(y)))
```

However, the processing time is really long. With a small sample of my dataset, I have processing times several minutes long. (And R crashes with a tenth of the dataset). Meanwhile, the function `Vector`-->`Geoprocessing tools`--> `Difference` in `QGIS` takes 83 seconds with a tenth of the dataset.

```
erase(forest_sp, roads_sp)
#2.83488 minutes 
forest_sp-roads_sp
#2.8698 minutes
st_erase(forest, roads) 
#58.77sec
```

Is there a function in R performs this operation quickly? Or is R inferior to QGIS in processing times for this kind of spatial function?

**Background**

There are multiple questions on gis.stackexchange that deal with this type of problem. Some are with the `sp` format and suggest `gDifference` or `erase` (or its analog polygon1-polygon2):

Erase, gDifference

[Clip polygon and retain data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64537/clip-polygon-and-retain-data)

gDifference

[Remove parts of line that fall within a polygon](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62929/remove-parts-of-line-that-fall-within-a-polygon/62933#62933)

[Identify area within one shapefile not in another shapefile in R](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213815/identify-area-within-one-shapefile-not-in-another-shapefile-in-r)

[Reverse clipping (erasing ) in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109639/reverse-clipping-erasing-in-r/109642#109642)

Other questions suggest solutions with the `sf` format:
st_difference

[Reverse clipping (erasing ) in R?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109639/reverse-clipping-erasing-in-r/254062#254062)

[Using simple features (sf) in R, how do I erase polygons overlapping with another layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/240259/using-simple-features-sf-in-r-how-do-i-erase-polygons-overlapping-with-anothe/240682#240682)

[ogr2ogr equivalent of QGIS Union](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/251440/ogr2ogr-equivalent-of-qgis-union)

All state that they perform that same thing (remove intersecting portions) and the official `tag` definition on gis.stackexchange states that a difference operation removes sections. However, I have found that often they don't. 
For example, `gDifference` with `byID=FALSE` that merges all into one MULTIPOLYGON does remove overlapping sections but `gDifference` with `byID=TRUE` that keeps polygons separate includes overlapping sections. With `sf`, `st_difference` also keeping overlapping sections and ends up with 10x as many polygons as my original file.

[image]

However, `erase` and the helper function `st_erase` do work as expected.

[image]

*Difference*

> A "difference" operation is a geoprocessing operation that completely
>   removes one overlapping polygon and the intersection of that polygon
>   from the other. It uses one polygon to "take a bite" out of another.

*Erase*

> The action of removing data attributes or features through the
>   processes of positive or negative selection and deletion.

Comment: have you tried st_sym_difference?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `rmapshaper` package offers a faster function for "erasing" or finding the difference between two polygon layers in R. Below is a comparison of the `st_erase` approach with `sf` and the `ms_erase` function in `rmapshaper`.

```
# Let's try an example using publicly available Census vector layers through `tigris`
if(!require(dplyr)){install.packages("dplyr")}
library(dplyr)
if(!require(sf)){install.packages("sf")}
library(sf)
if(!require(tigris)){install.packages("tigris")}
library(tigris)
if(!require(rmapshaper)){install.packages("rmapshaper")}
library(rmapshaper)

# First download two separate layers that overlap. We'll use a layer of Census 
# tracts and a layer of areal water features for Worcester County in Massachusetts.
# worcester_tracts has 172 obs and  10 variables; about 285KB in size.
worcester_tracts <- tracts(state = "MA", county = "Worcester", cb = TRUE) %>% 
  st_transform(., crs = 2805) %>% # use projected layers when doing geometric stuff
  st_make_valid()
# worcester_water has 3,270 obs and 9 variables; about 4.9MB in size. 
worcester_water <- area_water(state = "MA", county = "Worcester") %>% 
  st_transform(., crs = 2805) %>% 
  st_make_valid()

# Start with st_erase function. Note that I altered function slightly by removing 
# the st_combine function because it throws an error and isn't necessary. 
# Takes about 27 secs.
st_erase = function(x, y) st_difference(x, st_union(y))
system.time(erased_tracts1 <- st_erase(worcester_tracts, worcester_water))

# Now try it with ms_erase. Takes about 4.3 secs; over 6x faster. 
system.time(erased_tracts2 <- ms_erase(worcester_tracts, worcester_water))
```

The results are identical. You can speed things up even more by retaining as few variables, or attributes, as possible in the layers when doing these operations. Also, if your computer memory is being overwhelmed, consider breaking up the process into smaller geographic chunks (e.g., municipalities, counties, a grid), rather than working on the whole dataset at one time.

Comment: Thanks for coming back to a really old question! I am glad to be able to integrate R back into my workflow for this operation.

Comment: If you computer is lagging, it's time for some Split-Apply-Combine using lapply.  https://r-crash-course.github.io/12-plyr/

Answer (score 2):

It looks like something has been updated in `sf` or `rmapshaper` as `sf` runs faster on my system now (see benchmark below).

Also if you only do the intersection on features that `st_intersect()` this can speed up the operation a little too. It can make a big difference if your *x* is much smaller than your *y* or vice versa.

```
### Install/load packages
# Install packages if you dont have them
if(!require(dplyr)){install.packages("dplyr")}
if(!require(sf)){install.packages("sf")}
if(!require(tigris)){install.packages("tigris")}
if(!require(rmapshaper)){install.packages("rmapshaper")}
if(!require(rbenchmark)){install.packages("rbenchmark")}

# load packages
library(dplyr)
library(sf)
library(tigris)
library(rmapshaper)
library(rbenchmark)


### Load Example layers
worcester_tracts <- tracts(state = "MA", county = "Worcester", cb = TRUE) %>% 
  st_transform(., crs = 2805) %>% # use projected layers when doing geometric stuff
  st_make_valid()
worcester_water <- area_water(state = "MA", county = "Worcester") %>% 
  st_transform(., crs = 2805) %>% 
  st_make_valid()


### User created functions to benchmark
# Getting difference of geoms of x and y that partially intersect
st_erase_big = function(x, y){
  x$ref <- 1:nrow(x)
  x_inter = x[apply(st_intersects(x,y), 1, any),] #x in y
  y_inter = y[apply(st_intersects(y,x), 1, any),] #y in x
  difference <- st_difference(x_inter, st_union(y_inter)) #x_inter not in y_inter
  nointer_x = x[!x$ref %in% x_inter$ref,] # x not intersecting
  dplyr::bind_rows(difference,nointer_x)
} 


st_erase = function(x, y) st_difference(x, st_union(y))


### Benchmarking
benchmark("st_erase" = {st_erase(worcester_tracts, worcester_water)},
          "ms_erase" = {ms_erase(worcester_tracts, worcester_water)},
          "st_erase_big" = {st_erase_big(worcester_tracts, worcester_water)},
          replications = 5,
          columns = c("function", "replications", "elapsed","relative"))
```

The fastest is `st_erase_big` by a whisker, closely followed by `st_erase` and ~50% slower is `ms_erase`

```
 function     replications elapsed relative
 ms_erase            5   30.31    1.452
 st_erase            5   21.05    1.008
 st_erase_big        5   20.88    1.000
```

Comment: I also wonder whether a function in `terra` might be faster. I will try to look into it soon. Very much appreciated to add a new answer to an old question with updated packages. R spatial processing has changed so much in 4 years!

Comment: Thanks @user3386170. It is also worth checking out the geos package (https://github.com/paleolimbot/geos). A nice summary here: https://grantmcdermott.com/fast-geospatial-datatable-geos/. it is is faster for some geospatial operations, and looks to be a lot faster soon for others. The sfarrow package is also much quicker to read and write spatial data and has much smaller file sizes too (geoparquet), but warning: it can be a bit unstable at times.